# Jenkins adding special characters to shell commands

Tags: shell, encoding, jenkins

So, I have this Jenkins build in which I am transferring the final build to a deployment server. I have a copy command which I am doing in the deployment server from the Jenkins. However, Jenkins seems to be adding some unencoded characters to the cp, due to which it is failing. Here is the command which I have given directly in the Jenkins shell:

```
cp $BUILD_NUMBER/*.war /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps
```

and here is the console output of Jenkins with the unencoded characters:

```
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [cp 33/*.war /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps/
bash /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/catalina.sh start] ...
SSH: EXEC: connected
cp: cannot stat ���33/*.war���: No such file or directory
Tomcat started.
```

Ignore the Tomcat starting step. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get that output to be sent to a text file or piped to something like `xxd`/`hexdump` to see what those characters actually are?

Answer (score -1):

More likely you have saved some special (non-printing or non-standard whitespace) character in that line of the script. Try hexdumping your script and checking whether `$BUILD_NUMBER/*.war` really is flanked by *just* space characters. Just run `hexdump < script.sh` or run `hexdump` and paste the script, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to finish the input.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do a hexdump for a shell script?